# Feign Unit Testing Not found response

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to implement a unit test involving a FeignClient call which should return a 404 Not Found.

As Feign is trowing a FeignException for 404, what is the proper way to implement this test case?

I'm trying something like this...

```
when(mockedApiClient.userDataDelete(anyString()))
                .thenThrow( ... );
```

What should I throw?

Answer (score 13):

Feign Already provides inner classes like NotFound and other typica HTTP response code types. An example is shown here.

```
Request request = Request.create(Request.HttpMethod.GET, "url",
                    new HashMap<>(), null, new RequestTemplate());
            throw new FeignException.NotFound("", request, null);
```

Just modify the above as per your needs! Key point to note is that Request object is mandatory. As of 2021 few overloads like Request.create are deprecated. Look out for what you use!

Hope that helps! happy Coding!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

Mock your `FeignException`:

```java
var ex = Mockito.mock(FeignException.class);
Mockito.when(ex.status()).thenReturn(404);
Mockito.when(mockedApiClient.userDataDelete(anyString()))
       .thenThrow(ex);
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, to me worked as below (i used EasyRandom as generator of some fields):

```
private EasyRandom easyRandom = new EasyRandom();
 Map<String, Collection<String>> headersError = easyRandom.nextObject(HashMap.class);
 byte[] bodyError = easyRandom.nextObject(byte[].class);

 when(mockedApiClient.userDataDelete(anyString())
                .thenThrow(FeignException.errorStatus(
                        "userDataDelete",
                        Response.builder()
                                .status(404)
                                .reason("message error")
                                .request(Request.create(
                                        Request.HttpMethod.POST,
                                        "foo/foo/bar/v1/delete-data-user",
                                        headersError, //this field is required for construtor//
                                        null,
                                        null,
                                        null))
                                .body(bodyError)//this field is required for construtor
                                .build())
                );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine ;) . I've found that Instead of building the whole `headersError` you can simply pass an empty map: `Collections.emptyMap()`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless any other better solution is provided, this is how I have overcome this...

```
when(mockedApiClient.userDataDelete(anyString()))
                .thenThrow(FeignException.errorStatus(
                        "userDataDelete",
                        Response.builder()
                                .status(404)
                                .headers(new HashMap<>())
                                .reason("Not found").build()));
```

Comment: i donno why, but i get illegalstateexception instead of feign exception

Answer (score 2):

To return 404 Feign Exception on mocking the service, you can try out these things :

1. create your own exception class which will extends Feign Exception.
2. Annotate Response Status with value of HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.
3. Override the constructor as given below :

```
import feign.FeignException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class SampleFeignClientException extends FeignException {

    public SampleFeignClientException (String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public SampleFeignClientException (String message, Throwable cause, byte[] content) {
        super(message, cause, content);
    }

    public SampleFeignClientException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public SampleFeignClientException (int status, String message, byte[] content) {
        super(status, message, content);
    }
}
```

4. In Junit Test case dothrow the created sampleFeignException class.

```
    @Test
    public void sampleTestMethod() {
        SampleFeignClientException sampleFeignClientException = new sampleFeignClientException(404, "NOT FOUND", new byte[1]);

         doThrow(sampleFeignClientException).when(mockService).method();

 }
```

I hope this may helps you to resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Request request = mock(Request.class);

 when(someClient.someGetRequest(List.of(doc.getId())))
            .thenThrow(new FeignException.NotFound("message", request, null, null));
```

You can avoid create Request, only mocking it.

Comment: This won't work. It gives a MockitoException saying "Mockito cannot mock/spy because (bunch of lines)"